# Changing the login timeout for TTY

Tags: boot, 16.10

I have problem with the login into TTY1 during the boot sequence to Ubuntu 16.10. It times out too quickly for me to complete my password entry.

In `/etc/login.defs` `LOGIN_TIMEOUT` is set to `60`.

Resetting the value does not change the time out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `resetting` the value you should edit `/etc/login.defs` and change the LOGIN_TIMEOUT value. to higher value (e.g. 600)

```
# Max time in seconds for login
#
LOGIN_TIMEOUT       600
```